# Why do I get a TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'int'

Tags: python, typeerror

Sorry for the short essay but I think context is important here.  This is for a course but I have struggled the entire semester with grasping this and the teacher hasn't been much help to me personally.

I have a dataset with 30 categories and 500 images in each category (google maps stills of specific terrain).  The goal is to process the image features (I'm using opencv SIFT) and conduct PCA on the features.  I need to run the images through a deep learning model using fisher vectors and then plot some information based on the model.

The problem is I keep getting random errors that I don't believe trace to the original problem.  I know there is a crucial issue with my code, but I don't know what I don't know about it so I'm hoping the geniuses on stack can help identify my foible(s).

Here is the snippet where I am currently getting stuck:

#Ugly code, very sorry

```
for ind, label in enumerate(os.listdir(img_direc)):
    #labels is storing the integer values of each category of the images ('swamp_lands', 'mountain', etc)
    labels.append(ind)

    #temporary list to store features
    desc_list = []
        
    for i in os.listdir(f"{img_direc}\\{label}")[:400]:

        #process_image reads each file, converts to grayscale and resizes to a 224,224 image
        img = process_image(f"{img_direc}\\{label}\\{i}")
        _, desc = SIFT_Process_Keypoints(img)

        #first real point of confusion.  I know there is a need to create either a 0's or 1's matrix
        #to fill in any none-type gaps but I'm struggling with the theory and code behind that

        feat_mtx = np.ones((224,224))
        try:
            feat_mtx = np.zeros(desc.shape)
            for int, j in enumerate(desc):
                feat_mtx[int] = j
        except:
            pass

        #Do I need the mean? When trying to conduct PCA on the features I kept getting errors until
        #I reduced the values to a single number but it still wasn't giving me the right information

        desc_list.append(np.mean(feat_mtx))

    desc_list = np.array(desc_list, dtype='object')
    desc_list = desc_list.flatten()
    train.append(desc_list)
```

Does it just feel like my code is out of order?  Or I'm missing a certain middle function somewhere.  Any help with clarification would be greatly appreciated, I will be working actively on this code to try and gain some further understanding.

Currently, the above code is yielding

```
 line 55, in <module>
    desc_list.append(np.mean(desc))
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 180, in mean
line 3432, in mean  
    return _methods._mean(a, axis=axis, dtype=dtype,
line 192, in _mean     
    ret = ret / rcount
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

after processing like 10 categories of images without an error.

Comment: Two things: Do not call errors you don't understand as random errors, they are not random. Include reproducible code, for example the function SIFT_Process_Keypoints is missing.

Comment: welcome. [tour], [ask], [mre].